# Histogram equalization for normalized image without histeq function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

i'm trying to make histogram equalization code for normalized image without builtin function in MATLAB like 'histeq'

I have normalized gray image that has values between [0,1]

```
    input_img = mat2gray(img);
```

and I have found an example code wihout histeq function

```
    for i=1:size(GIm,1)
        for j=1:size(GIm,2)
            value=GIm(i,j);
            freq(value+1)=freq(value+1)+1;
            probf(value+1)=freq(value+1)/numofpixels;
        end
    end

    sum=0;
    no_bins=255;

    %The cumulative distribution probability is calculated. 

    for i=1:size(probf)
       sum=sum+freq(i);
       cum(i)=sum;
       probc(i)=cum(i)/numofpixels;
       output(i)=round(probc(i)*no_bins);
    end

    for i=1:size(GIm,1)
        for j=1:size(GIm,2)
                HIm(i,j)=output(GIm(i,j)+1);
        end
    end

    figure,imshow(HIm);
    title('Histogram equalization');
```

but this code is applied to an image that has a grayscale of [0,255]

how should I apply this code to my grayscale normalized image?

my image size 450x450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code you have to compute a 256-bin histogram by scaling your image to fit it:

```
input_img_255 = round(input_img * 255);
```

and then use `input_img_255` with the code you have. `round` should be good enough to use the rounded double values as indices as in your code. If you want to be more exact you can use:

```
input_img_255 = uint8(round(input_img * 255));
```

so that the values are integers.